# how to get trap messages about cpu usage using snmpd.conf

Tags: ubuntu, net-snmp, snmpd

i'm trying to create a threshold for cpu usage in snmpd.conf.

i included the MIB in the configuration file for the cpu usage:

*.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.10.0*

but i really don't know what are the flags needed for me to monitor that. 
it is not like

*load 10 11 12*
and how to invoke the monitor command that will send the trap message when the cpu percentage exceeds the threshold

Answer (score 0):

To monitor CPU usage and other system resources I use **nagios3**.

**Nagios** can read data from **SNMP** and draw graphs and raise notifications if certain threshold is reached, nagios server should have apache install.

Since nagios needs configuration here is nice page for start
[Nagios installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/nagios.html)

target computer needs to have **SNMPd** installed

Answer (score 0):

There is **DisMan Event MIB** which is usually built with snmpd.

Basically you need to addin your **snmpd.conf**:

- *trapsink/trap2sink/informsink*
- *monitor* Statement

  [Here is the man page  for DisMan](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html#lbAX) and [some examples from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156289/net-snmp-getting-more-detail-into-disman-traps)