# NET-SNMP: Getting more detail into Disman Traps

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm working on traps using NET-SNMP and the DISMAN Event MIB

With the following snmpd.conf configuration:

```
createUser disman MD5 sercrt@1
rouser disman auth
agentSecName disman
#defaultMonitors yes
disk / 90%
disk /var 85%
disk /opt 95%
disk /opt/pkgs 90%
disk /ufda 90%
proc cron
proc rtrcopy 1 1
proc socks1081 1 1
# monitor must have ".." in the line
monitor -u disman -r 30 -o prNames.1 -o prErrMessage.1 "Cron not running" prErrorFlag.1 != 0
monitor -u disman -r 30 -o prNames.2 -o prErrMessage.2 "rtrcopy running" prErrorFlag.2 != 0
monitor -u disman -r 30 -o prNames.3 -o prErrMessage.3 "socks1081 running" prErrorFlag.3 != 0
monitor -u disman -r 30  -o dskPath.1 -o dskErrorMsg.1 "/ is below 90%" dskErrorFlag.1 != 0
monitor -u disman -r 30  -o dskPath.2 -o dskErrorMsg.2 "/var is below 90%" dskErrorFlag.2 != 0
monitor -u disman -r 30  -o dskPath.3 -o dskErrorMsg.3 "/opt is below 90%" dskErrorFlag.3 != 0
monitor -u disman -r 30 -o dskPath.4 -o dskErrorMsg.4 "/opt/pkgs is below 90%" dskErrorFlag.4 != 0
monitor -u disman -r 30  -o dskPath.5 -o dskErrorMsg.5 "/ufda is below 90%" dskErrorFlag.5 != 0
```

I find that the disman trap is populating the following variables:

```
$1 = mteHotTrigger           dskTable  
$2 = mteHotTargetNameThe     '' 
$3 = mteHotContextName       ''
$4 = mteHotOID               .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.100.2
$5 = mteHotValue             1
```

On an Event list this isn't very informative for Operators. I think if I could populate mteHotContextName, with the some kind of helpful text e.g. "/ is below 90%", then this would be much more useful

I can't see how to do this with the monitor directive

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That's actually what the -o switch is for: it lets you add additional objects to the notification being sent out.  In your case, if you want the "helpful text" that is included in the error message value, you are doing the right thing by using the -o switch to include those objects.  Why it's not working for you, I'm not sure.  But you don't need a separate monitor line per row entry.  Instead, use one that checks the value at every row.  For example, the `defaultMonitors` configuration token actually specifies this:

```
monitor   -o prNames -o prErrMessage "process table" prErrorFlag != 0
```

Which checks every prErrorFlag at once.

The name you're using in quotes is just the name of the trigger, and that information isn't sent in the trap and you can't force it to be, unfortunately.  It's simply an administrative name for the monitor that is used internally and in the DISMAN-MIB entries themselves to report the monitor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Even the example on http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:DisMan_Monitoring shows this configuration:

 monitor machineTooBusy hrProcessorLoad > 90

Comment: Returning these values:

    DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (6539) 0:01:05.39
    SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteTriggerFired
    DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotTrigger.0 = STRING: machineTooBusy
    DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotTargetName.0 = STRING:  
    DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotContextName.0 = STRING:     
    DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotOID.0 = OID: HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.769
    DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotValue.0 = INTEGER: 92

Comment: In our case, it looks like $mteHotTrigger is 'dskTable'. We have a disk alert, but we don't know what the nature of it is. It was for this reason, I was wondering if I could use $mteHotContextName. It's seemed like an appropriate choice and is available. Any idea how I can get that string populated?

Comment: No, the context is the SNMPv3 context which is *not* related to a random string.  It would normally be "" for the default, but you can change it but then you need to configure snmptrapd to accept those other contexts too.  Sorry, but that's not what you need.

Comment: Ah, ok. I appreciate your help anyhow. I wonder how anybody gets any value out of DISMAN traps... Maybe RMON can do a job here...

Comment: Actually, RMON is no good; too Network-focussed. I guess what I need is something more like syslog, which I'd use if I could. I only have traps available to me for this requirement... I'll do some more research...

Comment: The DISMAN work wasn't designed to "delivery everything".  The goal, when the IETF WG created the DISMAN-EVENT-MIB, was to have the agent do some basic tests and then send an alert to the manager that said "you should probably check me out; something is amiss".  IE, the goal was much more of a "notify the manager so it can pull and analyze the data", and not to make the agent itself into a full manager.

Comment: The notification should include the *ErrMessage objects, if you told it to include them, though...  I'd think that would be most of what you wanted.  But  part of the problem is that when the error condition goes away, the string goes blank again so you can't really know for certain why the error is gone, just that it is.